# merge statement issue(mainly for update ) incase block

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, console-application, sql-merge

i was trying to insert certain data from one table(`table1`) to another table(`table2`) in a way like if data is existing just update the data or insert the data .But the problem now i am facing is,when i added a last condition like if first_name like 'mss%' i have to do insert SERVICE_TYPE_ID 10 else 20.But it is not happening for this case condition and rest all case condition in success.So i would like to know what is wrong with the last case condtion

```
trim(b.first_name) like 'mss%'     
                                      THEN 10
                                      ELSE 20
```

this is mainly failing for Merge update section and inserting 20 instead of 10
Here is my full oracle query

```
MERGE INTO table2 a
USING table1 b ON (a.second_name = b.first_name)

WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET a.friendly_name = TRIM(b.friendly_name),
    a.account_number  = TRIM(b.account_no),
    a.ne_type         = TRIM(b.ci_type),
    a.service_type_id = CASE
                        WHEN upper(trim(b.company_name)) LIKE '%MWAN%'
                             OR upper(trim(b.company_name)) LIKE '%MGWAN%'
                             OR upper(trim(b.company_name)) LIKE '%MWLAN%'
                             OR upper(trim(b.company_name)) LIKE '%MLAN%'
                             OR upper(trim(b.company_name)) LIKE '%DDOS%'
                             OR trim(b.first_name) LIKE 'mss%'
                          THEN 10 ELSE 20 END,
    a.to_locate_in_gis ='Y'
  WHERE a.account_number <> b.account_no

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (ne_slno, second_name, company_id, ne_type, ne_status, service_type_id)
  VALUES (s_node_seq_nextval,
          TRIM(b.first_name), TRIM(b.company_id), 
          TRIM(b.ci_type), TRIM(b.ci_status),
      CASE
      WHEN upper(trim(b.company_name)) LIKE '%MWAN%'
           OR upper(trim(b.company_name)) LIKE '%MGWAN%'
           OR upper(trim(b.company_name)) LIKE '%MWLAN%'
           OR upper(trim(b.company_name)) LIKE '%MLAN%'
           OR upper(trim(b.company_name)) LIKE '%DDOS%'
           OR trim(b.first_name) LIKE 'mss%'
        THEN 10 ELSE 20 END)
  WHERE SUBSTR(b.first_name, 1, 1) != ' '
```

All case condition is success except the one which pointed `trim(b.first_name) like 'mss%'`

Comment: Do you have data in your table1.first_name column that starts with "mss" (in lower case)?

Comment: @Boneist Yes it has data like mss-testeronet-mai-rb etc datas

Comment: What result do you get if you do: `select count(*) from table1 where trim(b.first_name) like 'mss%';`?

Comment: @Boneist 11000 records are there

Comment: What about `select count(*) from table1 where first_name like 'mss%';`?

Comment: @ Boneist 56 records less ,is that the issue??if then what is the issue?

Answer (score 2):

In your insert, the last expression in your case statement is `trim(b.first_name) like 'mss%'`.

However, then insert part of your merge statement has a predicate of: `WHERE SUBSTR(b.first_name, 1, 1) != ' ')` which excludes all the rows where there are spaces before the `mss`.

That is likely to be the cause of your issue. I would suggest you either remove that predicate from the insert part or add `or trim(b.first_name) like 'mss%'` into the where clause.

Comment: i am confuse now,can you clear it. WHERE SUBSTR
                                    (
                                      b.first_name,
                                      1,1
                                    )
                                    != ' ' will not add any spaces then how it will add it up

Comment: `WHERE SUBSTR ( b.first_name, 1,1 ) != ' '` is saying "where the first character of the first_name column is not a space". Your case statement trims the spaces off both the front and end of the first_name column **before** checking whether the resultant string starts with `mss`. This means that even though you have rows matching that expression the case statement, your where clause is excluding most of them, as they have at least one space at the beginning of the first_name.